# Check if a df has any str value rowwise and create a new column with that value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `df` that looks like

**`df`**:

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2.0 | NaN | Text String 1 | 3.0 |
| Text String 2 | NaN | 3.0 | 2.0 |
| 2.0 | Text String 3 | 3.0 | NaN |

I want create a new column `new_column` that look for all the row values in the column, and as long as any column contains string like `[^A-Za-z\s]`, my `new_column` get that exact value

for example, my desired output is something like

| A | B | C | D | new_column |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2.0 | NaN | Text String 1 | 3.0 | Text String 1 |
| Text String 2 | NaN | 3.0 | 2.0 | Text String 2 |
| 2.0 | Text String 3 | 3.0 | NaN | Text String 3 |

I've tried `str.contains` or other df methods but the problem is to get the value for any column that has a text value, not from any specific column.

Thanks!

Comment: Can there be multiple columns with string values in the same row?

Comment: @Nick Only one column would have string values. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can write a function to select the string value from a row and then apply that to the dataFrame:

```py
def get_str(row):
    return [v for v in row if type(v) is str][0]

df['new_column'] = df.apply(get_str, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
               A              B              C    D     new_column
0            2.0            NaN  Text String 1  3.0  Text String 1
1  Text String 2            NaN            3.0  2.0  Text String 2
2            2.0  Text String 3            3.0  NaN  Text String 3
```

If a row might not contain a string value, you will need to check for that situation in `get_str` and return a default value e.g.

```py
def get_str(row):
    try:
        return [v for v in row if type(v) is str][0]
    except:
        return np.nan

df = pd.DataFrame({ 'A' : [2.0, 'Text String 2', 2.0, 3.0], 'B': [np.nan, np.nan, 'Text String 3', 2.0], 'C': ['Text String 1', 3.0, 3.0, np.nan], 'D': [3.0, 2.0, np.nan, 1.0] })

df['new_column'] = df.apply(get_str, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
               A              B              C    D     new_column
0            2.0            NaN  Text String 1  3.0  Text String 1
1  Text String 2            NaN            3.0  2.0  Text String 2
2            2.0  Text String 3            3.0  NaN  Text String 3
3            3.0            2.0            NaN  1.0            NaN
```

Comment: thanks! when testing this on the actual df, I get "list index out of range" error

Comment: @FloriaT do you have rows with no string value? if so, what do you want in `new_column`?

Comment: @FloriaT also, did you note my edit (I left off the `axis=1` on `apply`

Comment: oh right I do see a column with just NaN and numbers. If that's the case, how do I add the else statement for when no str value, just return np.nan?

Comment: @FloriaT see my edit

Comment: @FloriaT that is weird, it certainly works for the small example above

Comment: @FloriaT see for example https://ideone.com/xQLLlw

Comment: thank u! I rechecked the df and there isn't any col with no str value. Then I applied def get_str(row):
    return [v for v in row if type(v) is str][0] 
df23_sub['new_column'] = df23_sub.apply(get_str, axis=1), again and it now worked. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @FloriaT no worries - I'm glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

You can reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and select strings columns by regex:

```
s = df.stack()
df['new_column'] = s[s.astype('str').str.contains('(^[A-Za-z\s])')].droplevel(1)
```

Similar idea is comvert values to numeric if possible and get non numeric strings values:

```
s = df.stack()
df['new_column'] = s[pd.to_numeric(s, errors='coerce').isna()].droplevel(1)
```

--

Or join values by `,` and select strings with number pattern:

```
df['new_column'] = df.astype('str').agg(','.join, 1).str.extract('([A-Za-z\s]+\d+)')
print (df)
               A              B              C    D     new_column
0            2.0            NaN  Text String 1  3.0  Text String 1
1  Text String 2            NaN            3.0  2.0  Text String 2
2            2.0  Text String 3            3.0  NaN  Text String 3
```

Comment: thanks! but I get the following integer output when I use the above code:

Comment: @FloriaT - answer was edited.

Comment: thank u!! but somehow for my actual df I get "nan nan 2" as the 1st value and some similar things(like nan nan String)  in other rows as well. Below answer worked.